# Restore/copy GPT+EFI disk backups to new disk and make bootable

Tags: boot, uefi

I've been going in circles. My situation is as follows:

- old disk died, it was a GPT disk booting EFI with 3 partitions, sda1=fat32 (flagged esp,boot and containing /boot and /EFI), sda2=etx4 (containing the rest, as well as the typical /boot), sda3=swap (linuxswap);
- I have backups (made using rsync -aAXH) of the *contents* of both sda1 and sda2
- I have a new disk and a bootable Ubuntu 20.04.3 USB stick

I want to restore the backups onto the new disk and make it bootable.

What I've tried (unsuccessfully):

- boot from the usb stick, gparted sda and made it GPT, then recreated the same 3 partitions, sda1=fat32 and flagged it esp,boot, sda2=ext4, sda3=swap
- restored all contents from old sda1 backup to new sda1, and from old sda2 to new sda2
- edited (sda2)/etc/fstab and updated the UUIDs with the new values from `lsblk`
- edited (sda1)/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg and updated the UUID of the search.fs_uuid line
- installed grub-efi-amd64 and attempted `grub-install /dev/sda`

The last line fails with:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory
```

Obviously, ignoring that and rebooting does show the grub menu, but doesn't actually boot once I choose an entry. I think the only step that's missing is to update the UUIDs in (sda2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg since the ones there are still the old ones. This is normally done with update-grub if I'm not wrong (?).

Can someone please help with a list of steps and commands? What am I missing?

**FULL DISCLOSURE:** I'm attempting this first in a VMware virtual machine, whose .vmx was modified to use UEFI firmware (add `firmware = "efi"` in the .vmx). This fully emulates a UEFI machine as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Looks like you did things correctly. What exactly is error? But if saying i386, have you booted in BIOS mode? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred just as you replied I had edited my question to specify I'm in a vmware VM, which I just realized was left in BIOS. I changed it to UEFI (added `firmware = "efi"` in .vmx) and then booted the Ubuntu .iso again. After installing grub-efi-amd64 and trying again `grub-install /dev/sda` then error is *Installing for x86_64-efi platform
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory*

Comment: @oldfred here's the bootinfo summary https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vnXJt2pzGy/ ... many thanks for your prompt reply (it already nudged me forward reading that report)

Comment: You are showing an ESP, but 16.04 is obsolete and you will not get repository to have updated software. Use 20.04 or other current version. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: @oldfred sure 16.04 is dated (though still supported), but it's besides the point -- the question was about how to make the new disk bootable

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but I'm not accepting it as answer yet, because I'm still interested in a clear set of steps to fix it manually.

Using the pointers by @oldfred in a comment above, I used `boot-repair` which fixed it in one go.

I installed `boot-repair` after booting from a live CD, using the ppa (and *not* the ISO, which apparently is buggy), i.e.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

then chose to apply all default fixes, which worked in my case (note that I had backups and was in a VM so I could afford to be adventurous).

In the end it seems that it did was what I suspected: updated the UUIDs in grub.cfg, which would have been a bit of a pain to do manually, so I was indeed close.

Answer (score -1):

You need like:

```
pacstrap /mnt base linux linux-firmware
pacstrap /mnt grub-bios
```

when startup PC also configure bios to Bios in secure boot (not EFI or how there...)